# Literal values in CGRectMake and retina

Tags: ios, retina-display, cgrectmake

if I have this line of code in my app will IOS do an automatic translation to retina?

so:

```
self.cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
```

would automatically become on iPad3:

```
self.cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2048, 1536)];
```

Thanks

Comment: you have to ignore the resolution of Retina Screen, the iOS will do it on that devices which is capable for it instead of you, you always have to work with the normal geometry.

Comment: so this self.cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; is the correct way?

Comment: yes, in your code, it is the proper way, exactly. you would find more information about this **[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC)**, if you are hungry for the information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This would create one view the size of the screen, and the other twice the size.  Core Graphics handles measurements in points, not pixels.